# How can I add a line below the navigation bar xcode

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I want a line with a color that i have hex code or rbg numbers of it. Just like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small UIView subclass that will do just that:

```
@interface LineView : UIView
-(instancetype)initWithNavigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navBar;
-(void)colorRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue;
-(void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height;
@end

@implementation LineView

-(instancetype)initWithNavigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navBar {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [navBar addSubview:self];
        // Default height
        CGFloat height = 2.0;
        [navBar.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
        [navBar.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:navBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:height]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)colorRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}

-(void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
            constraint.constant = height;
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

To use, in your UIViewController class's/subclass's viewDidLoad method do this:

```
LineView *view = [[LineView alloc]initWithNavigationBar:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
[view colorRed:0.9451 green:0.4824 blue:0.3020];
```

Comment: I am not an experienced developer. Can you tell me what i need to do to make it work ?

Comment: I pasted below all the code in my .m file but it didn't work

Comment: I paste the first code below <@end> in my .m file and the second in my viewDidLoad method but:
Use of undeclared identifier 'LinewView' for the first line and

No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'colorRed:green:blue:' for the second line

Comment: I described the errors, I have 2 errors. I can't even run the app. And yes I have collectionviewcontroller in a navigationcontroller

Comment: Post the first code above your @end in your .m file instead of below the @end!

Comment: still the same errors. I placed the first code above @end in my .m file and the second one in viewDidLoad
http://s27.postimg.org/vfok5bkoz/Screen_Shot_2014_08_06_at_20_39_08.png

Comment: When I say place it above `@end` (your implementation section) I really mean above the `@implementation`.

Comment: Okey I did it and now the app doesn't launch and this happens:
http://s15.postimg.org/6szd0o6wb/Screen_Shot_2014_08_06_at_20_46_36.png

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thanks. I don´t get why the question is considered off-topic, it´s been a great help